# Can instead of docker pull just pull the hash from repo, without the image?

Tags: docker

I can get a hash of local docker image with

```
docker inspect --format='{{index .RepoDigests 0}}' myimage:latest
```

Can I get the same for a remote image? Something like

```
docker pull --hash-only cr.yandex/12345/myimage:latest
```

Or another thing that could solve my problem (pulling image on very low disk space machines): how to make docker pull auto delete old unused layers **before** pulling updated layers.

Answer (score 3):

With docker itself:

```
$ docker buildx imagetools inspect busybox --format '{{json .Manifest.Digest}}'
"sha256:2376a0c12759aa1214ba83e771ff252c7b1663216b192fbe5e0fb364e952f85c"
```

External tools that implement this include Google's crane, RedHat's skopeo, and my own regclient.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [skopeo](https://github.com/containers/skopeo) for this,

Example: https://github.com/containers/skopeo/tree/main#show-properties-of-fedoralatest